# xpath find inside script tag

Tags: xml, google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I'm using Google Sheets to extract content from [THIS PAGE](http://online.northcarolina.edu/exams/find.php?q%5Bmode%5D=next&q%5Btext%5D=Spearfish%2C%20South%20Dakota%2C%20USA&q%5Bnsg%5D=Y&q%5Bloc%5D=&q%5Bsptext%5D=&q%5Bhasloc%5D=Y&q%5Bgb%5D=&q%5Bhasmoved%5D=Y&q%5Bhasdist%5D=&bounds%5Beast%5D=-118.14889347262965&bounds%5Bnorth%5D=34.38151088113997&bounds%5Bwest%5D=-118.82317936130153&bounds%5Bsouth%5D=34.1556665680419&result_center%5Blat%5D=34.26866454346142&result_center%5Blon%5D=-118.48603641696559&&m[setvp]=Y&m[vp][lat]=34.296535816292305&m[vp][lon]=-118.44596421428307&m[vp][zoom]=12&m[setwin]=Y&m[win][cent]=25112&m[win][loc]=28574&m[win][tab]=0&m[mtype]=roadmap) using xpath.

Using importXML(), I am able to extract HTML nodes easily via xpath, e.g., using: `//*[@id='result_listing_1_0']/div[1]`

However, when I try to extract something that's inside a script tag, I get an error (e.g., when using xpath such as `//*[@id='exam_info_window_content_0_0']` ). In this case, the ID is inside a script tag.

How can I use xpath to extract HTML that's inside the script tag in a web page's source.

Update: here's an example of the output I want:

> Notes for students:
>
> Students must present a valid/legible photo ID
>   before each appointment. Electronic devices are not permitted during
>   appointments unless otherwise stated in exam instructions (no cell
>   phones; cell phones may not be used as calculators). Students must
>   leave cell phones at home, in a locked car, or in the care of the
>   proctor. All appointments must be confirmed in advance.
>
> Fee details:
>
> computer-based exam - $40 for two hours paper-based exam
>   - $30 for two hours
>
> Website:
>
> http://www.csun.edu/testing   (without escape characters
>   this is: http:www.csun.edu/testing)
>
> ---
>
> Notes for students:
>
> Students must present a valid/legible photo ID
>   before each appointment. Electronic devices are not permitted during
>   appointments unless otherwise stated in exam instructions (no cell
>   phones; cell phones may not be used as calculators). Students must
>   leave cell phones at home, in a locked car, or in the care of the
>   proctor. All appointments must be confirmed 24 hours in advance.
>
> Fee details:
>
> 25$ covers a single visit. Multiple tests may be taken at
>   one visit. Free parking.
>
> Website:
>
> http://www.spectrumlearningcenters.com    (without escape
>   characters this is: www.spectrumlearningcenters.com)

The output will be extracted from the map markers on the page:
[image]
[image]

Comment: What exactly should the result look like? What would you like to display in the result cell?

Comment: very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28655014/xpath-to-extract-multiple-id-tags-with-the-same-id

Comment: @MathiasMüller Thank you for your comment. I updated my question to contain a couple of screen-shots. The goal is to extract all the text in all the map markers in the page.

Comment: Screenshots are not clear enough. Please add the actual **text**, exactly what you would like to get in a Google Sheet. But before you do, read Quentin's answer. Most likely, you can only get this content as text.

Comment: @MathiasMüller Added example of the exact output I'm seeking. I do want the content as text, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Script elements contain only text nodes.

You would need to either match the text (with `contains`) or get the entire text node, extract the HTML from it, parse that HTML into a DOM and then run XPath on the new DOM.